# file download pop up is not coming

Tags: java, download

Wrote a simple code to download a file from file system but still not getting download pop up hence file is not downloading ,not even throwing any error .Please help me out.Following is my code written on controller side.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "download", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        String fileName="/home/test/Testing.xlsx";
        PrintWriter out=null;

        try{
            System.out.println(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+"fileName");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
            response.setHeader( "Pragma", "public" );
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) );
            out = response.getWriter();
            int i;
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            out.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here mistake was POST method, we should not use post method instead we should always use GET method while writing program for download.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "download", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody void download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
            String fileName="/home/test/Testing.xlsx";
            PrintWriter out=null;

            try{
                System.out.println(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1)+"fileName");
                response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
                response.setHeader( "Pragma", "public" );
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) );
                out = response.getWriter();
                int i;
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                while ((i = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(i);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                out.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }


        }
```